# Android parse sub XML tag

Tags: android, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed>
    <entry>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Margherita</name>
        <cost>155</cost>
        <description>Single cheese topping</description>
        <list>
            <author>PPShein</author>
            <authorurl>http://www.ppshein.net</authorurl>
        </list>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Double Cheese Margherita</name>
        <cost>225</cost>
        <description>Loaded with Extra Cheese</description>
        <list>
        <author>Mike</author>
        <authorurl>http://www.mike.net</authorurl>
    </list>        
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I've got problem to parse above XML file. It's fine for me to parse "id, name, cost and discription" by using [this example](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) of android.

But for `<author>` and `<authorurl>` tag, example of above link cannot fulfill my task. Please help me how to parse sub tag of this XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Just go through a **DOM Parser**. You can get the particular Node by its name. Actually its works same as other node, you have to just get the `NodeList` for `list` element which has child nodes `author` and `authorurl`.

Look at these

**[Tutorial 1](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/)
[Tutorial 2](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)**

Answer (score 0):

1.I have parsed this xml i think this one help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rootelement1>
    <subelement> Hello XML Sub-Element 1</subelement>
    <subelement> Hello XML Sub-Element 2 
        <subsubelement>
          Sub Sub Element 
         </subsubelement>
   </subelement>
</rootelement1>
```

> 2.extratct xml is here

```
private String getEventsFromAnXML(Activity activity)
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Resources res = activity.getResources();
        XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.parsxml);
        xpp.next();
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                stringBuffer.append("--- Start XML ---");

            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                stringBuffer.append("\nSTART_TAG: " + xpp.getName());
                System.out.println("\n--- Start XML ---" + xpp.getName());
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                stringBuffer.append("\nEND_TAG: " + xpp.getName());
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                stringBuffer.append("\nTEXT: " + xpp.getText());
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
        stringBuffer.append("\n--- End XML ---");
        System.out.println("\n--- End XML ---");
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
```

[Reference from here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/04/read-xml-resources-in-android-using.html)